# Grails Production .War Deployment

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

A client that I deploy several web-apps to has a very slow disk array and some serious anti-virus scanning when exploding a .war file. The process of exploding the .war on my laptop takes about 5 minutes, but on the client's site it takes about 45 minutes. I would like to move everything from the web-apps lib directory (in the war file) to tomcat's lib directory. However, I can't seem to get Grails to not include the lib folder in the .war .

This is the top of my BuildConfig..groovy file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    fileset(dir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib" ).each {
    delete(file: it)
    }
}
```

Using Grails version 2.2.5

Comment: Only thing I can think of, since your code looks right, is that you have that specified under an environment block that isn't production?

Comment: I don't have it in an environment block, so shouldn't it be set for all environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    fileset(dir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib" ).each {
        delete(file: it)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything in the lib directory is still being included in the .war file

Comment: Strange. Worked for me. :). make sure this is not present inside `grails.project.dependency.resolution` by any chance.

Comment: I edited question to include to of my BuildConfig.groovy, also there's no grails.war.* in my Config.groovy file

Comment: Nevermind that did indeed work. I guess it needed a "grails compile --refresh-dependencies", I had only done a "grails clean" -> "grails war" to test. Everything appears to be working fine now. Thanks!